# Pass data in modal segue in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

My real problem is i want to pass data from childViewController to parentViewController in storyboard by **modal segue**.

**Code**

**parentViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *address;
```

**childViewController.m**

```
parentViewController *parent=(parentViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
post.address=@"Hello World";
```

This code throw **exception** like

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainTabbarViewController
>   setAddress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa070e6b910'

**storyboard structure**

TabbarController-> NavigationController-> parentViewController-> childViewController

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: @Devashi ... I think delegate is a better choice....`nsuserdefault`...ahhh...i don't think so....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get a reference to the segue that created you. You could create a property (sourceVC in my example) in the destination controller, and assign self to this property in the prepareForSegue method (in the source view controller):

[(ChildViewController *)segue.destinationViewController sourceVC] = self;

Anyway, I think it's a better solution to use a delegate.

*** In ChildViewController.h ***

```
@protocol ChildDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)postAddress:(NSString*)ad;
@end

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ChildDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

*** In ParentViewController.h ***

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <ChildDelegate>
@end
```

*** In ParentViewController.m ***

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
       ChildViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
       vc.delegate = self;
}
```

*** In ChildViewController.m ***

```
- (void)changeAddress:(NSString*)ad
{
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(postAddress:)])
    {
        // Tell the delegate something.
        [self.delegate postAddress:@"New Address"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is lengthy code. Pass data by nsuserdefault is better than this.What you say ?

Comment: I find is a really bad practice, but it is up to you how to use NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 2):

the proper way to do that is using delegate

in `ChildViewController.h`

```
@protocol ChildDelegate 
- (void)postAddress:(NSString *)address;
@end 
@interface ChildViewController
@property (nonAtomic, assign) id<ChildDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

in `ChildViewController.m`

```
[self.delegate postAddress:address];
```

in `ParentViewController.h`

```
@interface ParentViewController <ChildDelegate>
@end
```

in `ParentViewController.m`

```
// presenting childViewController
- (void)presentChildViewController {   
    ChildViewController *childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc]init];
    childViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:childViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


// delegate method
- (void)postAddress:(NSString *)address{
    // add you code here
}
```

Comment: I think it is lengthy code. Pass data by nsuserdefault is better than this.What you say ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass the data back to the parent view controller like this. Delegation is the best way to implement this.
Please have a look on the following link where it is explained in detail.

[passing-data-between-view-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: I think it is lengthy code. Pass data by nsuserdefault is better than this.What you say ?